# You have to provide the query parameter when trying to curl Neo4j

Tags: curl, neo4j

I get this error message:

```
You have to provide the 'query' parameter ...
```

when I try to use `Neo4j` rest api. The way I do it is through `curl`:

```
$ curl 'http://neo4j:root@127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/cypher' -d '
  {
     "query": "START n=node(*) RETURN distinct labels(n)", "params":{}
  }'
```

If however I run the same query programmatically using one library in `Python`, then it's ok - I get some results back. So, what else should I specify to make my `curl` command work?

Comment: `-X POST` and `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'` helped me to do the trick

Comment: `-X POST` is not necessary in fact. `-H` is enough.

Comment: you should also use the more recent endpoint /db/data/transaction/commit, see: neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Neo server is expecting a content type of `application/json` which may be specified by default in your client, but not in cURL. Specifying the content type directly with an `-H` parameter to cURL should work, something like

```
$ curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' \    
  'http://neo4j:root@127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/cypher' -d '
  {
     "query": "START n=node(*) RETURN distinct labels(n)", "params":{}
  }'
```

On my machine:

```
[~/apps/neo]$ curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json'     'http://neo4j:root@127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/cypher' -d '
  {
     "query": "START n=node(*) RETURN distinct labels(n)", "params":{}
  }'
{
  "columns" : [ "labels(n)" ],
  "data" : [ [ [ "Movie" ] ], [ [ "Person" ] ], [ [ "PublicDomain" ] ] ]
}
```

Without the content-type header, I see the same error you do.

Interestingly, as you pointed out in the comments, you can invoke this request without the `-X POST` option to cURL. This works because of the presence of the `-d` parameter which forces the POST method.